# Positioning a :before selector

Tags: css, icons, pseudo-element

When adding a `:before` selector, in this scenario I am trying to insert a Phone Icon to appear above the `.front-page-contact` div. Ideally, so it would be centered above the text in the `.front-page-contact` div.

How could I go about positioning this selector to achieve the result mentioned above?

```
 .front-page-contact .widget:nth-of-type(1) {
    text-align: center;
 }

.front-page-contact {
    background-color: #00AFBE;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.front-page-contact h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.front-page-contact h2:before {
    font-family: Ionicons;
    content: "\f4b8";
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Current position of the Pseudo element]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give h2 `position: relative` then the pseudo element will position itself absolutely to the h2 not to the page. Its hard to say more without seeing the markup.

**EDIT:**

Change it to:

```
.front-page-contact h2:before {
    font-family: Ionicons;
    content: "\f4b8";
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1em;
    left: calc(50% - 40px);
    top: -60px;
}
```

Adjust left / top as necessary

Comment: I've added more markup and a better screenshot to show the position of the element when adding `position: relative` to the `h2` class.
I added `position: relative` to the pseudo element as well which positioned the icon above the `h2`. However, it's  expanded the height of the `.front-page-contact`. There is a nice example from this WordPress Theme: [WordPress Theme](http://therapy.axiomthemes.com/)